# How to build a proper form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to build a form_tag that will allow me to post a new note to a client. My rake routes look like:

```
[hchq (master)]$ rake routes
    user_notes GET    /users/:user_id/notes(.:format)          notes#index
               POST   /users/:user_id/notes(.:format)          notes#create
 new_user_note GET    /users/:user_id/notes/new(.:format)      notes#new
edit_user_note GET    /users/:user_id/notes/:id/edit(.:format) notes#edit
     user_note GET    /users/:user_id/notes/:id(.:format)      notes#show
               PUT    /users/:user_id/notes/:id(.:format)      notes#update
               DELETE /users/:user_id/notes/:id(.:format)      notes#destroy
         users GET    /users(.:format)                         users#index
               POST   /users(.:format)                         users#create
      new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                     users#new
     edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                users#edit
          user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#show
               PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#update
               DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                     users#destroy
      sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)                      sessions#create
   new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                  sessions#new
       session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)                  sessions#destroy
       clients GET    /clients(.:format)                       clients#index
               POST   /clients(.:format)                       clients#create
    new_client GET    /clients/new(.:format)                   clients#new
   edit_client GET    /clients/:id/edit(.:format)              clients#edit
        client GET    /clients/:id(.:format)                   clients#show
               PUT    /clients/:id(.:format)                   clients#update
               DELETE /clients/:id(.:format)                   clients#destroy
          root        /                                        clients#index
        signup        /signup(.:format)                        users#new
        signin        /signin(.:format)                        sessions#new
       signout DELETE /signout(.:format)                       sessions#destroy
```

Can I just post to the create action on the notes or do I need to get the new_user_note_path? Why? I have an at @client instance variable available in the controller.

This is what I currently have:

```
<%= form_tag(new_user_note_path, method: :get) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %> 
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new note" %> 
    </div>
<%= f.submit "New Note"%> 
<% end %>
```

Which gets me this error:

[image]

What I think needs to happen is I need to build a form_tag that either hits the create or new_user_note action of the controller. I think it needs to hit the new_user_note, now that I think about it more so that it can set the client id. Is this correct?

If so how do I structure my form_tag? Do I need to pass a hidden field with a client_id?

Also, what should my notes controller look like in regard to the new and create action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since user is a resource, your should `:post` to `users_notes_path`, which will be handled by `notes#create`, as it is meant to be for resources
2. Again, since user is a resource, why not user `form_for` ? (or simpleform/formtastic/whated suits you) ?

Comment: `<%= form_for(user_notes_path) do |f| %>` gets me `No route matches {:controller=>"notes"}`

Answer (score 1):

Does your user resource map to a User model?  If it does then form_for is your best bet.  When using form_for pass in the the instance variable

`<%= form_for @user do |f| %>`